# array_push expects one parameter to be array null given in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have following code

```
$newsheadline = array();
$crawler->filter('p.title > a')->each(function ($node) {
array_push($newsheadline, htmlentities($node->text()));
});
```

This gives me warning

```
array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

Comment: 1. It seems like you use a framework right? 2. The variable is out of scope! You can use `use()` e.g. `function ($node)use($newsheadline)` does that do the trick for you? (And you have a typo in your definition)

Comment: your `htmlentities($node->text())` seems null value

Comment: @Eko it is not null. I print it in next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable scope: `$newsheadline` isn't available to your closure, so you need to `use` it... and because you're modifying it in the closure, you'll need to pass it by reference as well

```
$crawler->filter('p.title > a')->each(
    function ($node) use (&$newsheadline) {
        array_push($newsheadline, htmlentities($node->text()));
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanx Mark, It works.  Could you please tell me about a link where I can read about closure. I didn't fully understand `Variable scope: $newsheadline isn't available to your closure`

Comment: Also there are two such arrays, When I write it like `function ($node) use (&$newsheadline) use(&$newsheadline2) {` I get error `syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE), expecting '{'`

Comment: If you need to provide multiple values via `use` then the syntax is `function ($node) use (&$newsheadline, &$newsheadline2) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$newshaedline = array();
$crawler->filter('p.title > a')->each(function ($node) {
      array_push($newsheadline, htmlentities($node->text()));
});
```

I think no need to save it again in the same array: $newsheadline

Comment: Why do you check if the same variable is different? That makes no sense!

Comment: I mistyped the code here. Actually I am just pushing the value to array. Sorry.